# How to check if a specific user is logged in laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

I am making one to one chat application and want to detect other user is online or not. The Auth::check() works for both users but i need a specific one.

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: I making a chat app with two users logged in at a same time. I want to update the status online or offline if they are not authenticated.

Comment: you have to store last activity

Comment: I am using this logic:

Comment: function updateOnlineStatus()
    {
        var user = {!! auth()->user() !!};
        if(user.id == 2 || user.id == 3) {
            $('#status').text('Online');
        }
   
    }

Comment: but the value of id changes each time i reload the page. Can't make perfect logic.